# Alter Keystate of Shift while using PostMessage

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke, postmessage

I'm currently trying to experiment with using PostMessage.

I got the hang of how to use it and apply different keys and such but I've met a problem:
When using PostMessage while I myself am pressing Shift or Ctrl, it will be a combined Keypress of Shift + Key.

In some situations this isnt optimal or actually wrong and I was wondering if it's possible to either ignore the Keystate of Shift or set it to No through Flags or something

```
        PostMessage(hWnd, WM_SYSKEYDOWN, VK_S, 0);
        PostMessage(hWnd, WM_SYSKEYUP, VK_S, 0);
```

I'm using it like this.
I've tried using WM_KEYDOWN and UP or WM_CHAR but it seems like my application doesn't react to WM_CHAR and WM_KEYDOWN does the same as WM_SYSKEYDOWN

Comment: *"I got the hang of how to use it"* - Do not fool yourself. [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513).

Comment: I didnt say that I fully understand the background to it but at least I am able to use it to achieve what I need in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to synthesize keyboard (or mouse) messages directly. Use SendInput instead.

Note, however, that this will still add the new input to the end of the message queue, so if you want to act like a certain key combination is pressed *right now* you will need to handle that situation in some other manner.

Comment: Does it work if the application I'm sending it to is in the background?

Comment: @Hoesl Can the background application receive keyboard input?

Comment: Yes, PostMessage works even if the application is in the background which is also an essential feature. Without that anything would be useless